# urllib.urlretrieve(file_url) - check if that server was available

Tags: python, urllib

I have

```
import urllib
the_result = urllib.urlretrieve(file_url)
```

how can I know if the connection with that file server was successful and I have the image?

if I do:

```
the_result[1]
```

I am getting only:

```
Server: ..
Date: ..
Content-type: ..
Connection: ..
X-Powered-by:..
Vary: ..
```

Comment: `the_result[0]` will be the path to the temporary file. Copy it to relevant place.